# Extract Value from JSON Object at run time

Tags: json, powershell

I am new to PowerShell am I am trying to figure out how to iterate over JSON objects in PowerShell and extract values.

I have a JSON object in a file WIMS.JSON

```
{ WIMS:{
    A:{drive:"A"},
    B:{drive:"Z"}
}}
```

I want to iterate over the objects in WIMS, ie A and B and select the different drive letter in a loop.

I have been able to work out how to get the object names (probably ugly) using

```
$json = (Get-Content "WIMS.json" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
$WIMS = $json.WIMS
$wimNames=$($WIMS| Get-Member -MemberType *Property).Name 
for ($i=0; $i -lt $wimNames.count; $i++) {
    write-host ("Property names are: " + $wimNames[$i])
    $object=$WIMS| select $wimNames[$i]   #does not work
    $object.drive  #does not work
}
```

But I am unable to figure out how to extract the objects so I can access the fields.

Any pointers would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are heading on the right track. Using `Select-Object` with the `-Expand` argument should get you what you want.

```
$wimNames | ForEach-Object {
    $object = $WIMS | Select-Object -Expand $_
    $object.drive 
}
```

or

```
$wimNames | ForEach-Object { $WIMS | Select-Object -Expand $_ | ForEach-Object { $_.drive } }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is a built-in cmdlet `convert-fromjson`

```
    $js = @"

    { WIMS:{
        A:{drive:"A"},
        B:{drive:"Z"}
    }}


    "@

    $jsobj = $js | ConvertFrom-Json
    $jsobj.WIMS.A
```